# MPV loadlist "<playlist>" - What is <playlist>?

Tags: playlist, mpv

I need some help to understand what concretely a playlist is in MPV.

I know that with the command `loadfile "<file>"`,  is the path to the music (or other) to play. But what is  ? Is it a path to a folder containing several files ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

Create a .m3u file by doing `ls *.mp3 > playlist.m3u`

And then `loadlist "path/to/playlist.m3u"`

Comment: More details of M3U format of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U. Generally you'll want to use m3u8 extension with UTF-8 data to support the possibility of Unicode filenames.